# cannot retrieve process id for global process name

Tags: process, elixir, global, worker, erlang-supervisor

I have a worker that is initialised as follows:

```
defmodule GenServerDB.Worker do                                                                                                                                                                                    
  use GenServer 

  def start_link(name) do                                                                                                                                                                                          
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, [name: {:global, {:name, name}}])                                                                                                                                        
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    {:ok, %{}}
  end

end
```

I can then create workers that I expect to be named using the `:global` module:

```
iex(3)> {:ok, pid} = Supervisor.start_link([Supervisor.Spec.worker(GenServerDB.Worker, [], [])], strategy: :simple_one_for_one)                                                                                          
{:ok, #PID<0.126.0>}
iex(4)> Supervisor.start_child(pid, [[1]])                                                                                                                                                                         
Supervisor.start_child(pid, [[1]])                                                                                                                                                                                 
{:ok, #PID<0.128.0>}                                                                                                                                                      
iex(6)> Supervisor.start_child(pid, [[2]])                                                                                                                                                                         
Supervisor.start_child(pid, [[2]])                                                                                                                                                                                 
{:ok, #PID<0.131.0>}                                                                                                                                                                                               
iex(7)> Supervisor.start_child(pid, [[3]])                                                                                                                                                                         
Supervisor.start_child(pid, [[3]])                                                                                                                                                                                 
{:ok, #PID<0.133.0>}
iex(8)> Supervisor.which_children(pid)                                                                                                                                                                             
Supervisor.which_children(pid)                                                                                                                                                                                     
[{:undefined, #PID<0.128.0>, :worker, [GenServerDB.Worker]},                                                                                                                                                       
 {:undefined, #PID<0.131.0>, :worker, [GenServerDB.Worker]},                                                                                                                                                       
 {:undefined, #PID<0.133.0>, :worker, [GenServerDB.Worker]}]
```

However when I try and get the `pid` for a given `name`, I get the following:

```
iex(9)> :global.whereis_name({:global, {:name, 1}})                                                                                                                                                                
:global.whereis_name({:global, {:name, 1}})                                                                                                                                                                        
:undefined
```

Am I missing something here? It looks like I haven't named the process properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the argument in the `:global.whereis_name/1` call. You don't need the `{:global` here and the name of the process is actually `{:name, [1]}`, so you need to call `:global.whereis_name({:name, [1]})`.

```
defmodule GenServerDB.Worker do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(name) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, [name: {:global, {:name, name}}])
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    {:ok, %{}}
  end
end

{:ok, pid} = Supervisor.start_link([Supervisor.Spec.worker(GenServerDB.Worker, [], [])], strategy: :simple_one_for_one)
Supervisor.start_child(pid, [[1]])
Supervisor.start_child(pid, [[2]])
Supervisor.start_child(pid, [[3]])
IO.inspect Supervisor.which_children(pid)
IO.inspect :global.whereis_name({:name, [1]})
```

Output:

```
[{:undefined, #PID<0.77.0>, :worker, [GenServerDB.Worker]},
 {:undefined, #PID<0.78.0>, :worker, [GenServerDB.Worker]},
 {:undefined, #PID<0.79.0>, :worker, [GenServerDB.Worker]}]
#PID<0.77.0>
```

Comment: Thanks - are there docs on the above explanation? I couldn't find elixir documentation on which part of `{:global, {:name, name}}` is the actual name of the process.

Comment: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-name-registration says "{:global, **term**}- the GenServer is registered globally **with the given term** using the functions in the :global module."